# Rotman Proposition 2.73: $|HK||H\cap K|=|H||K|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading the book "Advanced modern algebra" by Joseph J. Rotman. I have a problem in Proposition 2.73 at page 87.

> $\textbf{Proposition (Product Formula):}$ If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$, then
>   $$|HK| |H \cap K| = |H||K|,$$
>   where $HK = \{hk: h \in H \text{ and } k \in K \}.$
>
> $\textbf{Proof:}$ Define a function $f: H \times K \rightarrow HK$ by $f:(h,k) \mapsto hk$. Clearly, $f$ is a surjection. It suffices to show, for every $x \in HK$, that $|f^{-1}(x)| = |H \cap K|$, where $f^{-1}(x) = \{(h,k) \in H \times K: hk = x \}$, [because $H \times K$ is the disjoint union $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in H \times K} f^{-1}(x)$].
>   We claim that if $x = hk$, then
>   $$f^{-1}(x) = \{(hd,d^{-1}k): d \in H \cap K\}.$$
>   Each $(hd,d^{-1}k) \in f^{-1}(x)$, for $f(hd,d^{-1}k) = hdd^{-1}k = hk = x$. For the reverse inclusion, let $(h',k') \in f^{-1}(x)$, so that $h'k' = hk$. Then $h^{-1}h' = k'k^{-1} \in H \cap K$; call this element $d$. Then $h' = hd$ and $k' = d^{-1}k$, and so $(h',k')$ lies in the right side. Therefore,
>   $$|f^{-1}(x)| = |\{(hd,d^{-1}k):d \in H \cap K\}| = |H \cap K|,$$
>   because $d \mapsto (hd,d^{-1}k)$ is a bijection.

Intuitively, I feel that when $H \cap K = \emptyset$, then $f$ is a bijection. When $H \cap K \neq \emptyset$, then $f$ is a surjection, so I do not understand why $\forall x \in HK, |f^{-1}(x)| = |H \cap K|$ and how can we know $H \times K$ is the disjoint union $\displaystyle\bigcup_{x \in H \times K} f^{-1}(x)$. Thank all!

Comment: Hi: please avoid inane titles like "question about a problem."  I went ahead and substituted what you had with important things from your question which will make the question a lot more useful. Please try to do the same in the future.

Comment: Being subgroups, $H\cap K$ is never empty.

Comment: Oh yes, we have $e \in H \cap K$

Comment: But why $\forall x \in HK, |f^{-1}(x)|=|H \cap K|$?

Answer (score 2):

That is because we have a bijection:
\begin{align}
f^{-1}(x)&\longrightarrow H\cap K\\
(hd,d^{-1}k)&\longmapsto d
\end{align}